# How to make a new contract using remix with a function in which I want to get the user details from my already deployed contract on the blockchain

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

How to make a new contract using remix with a function in which I want to get the user details from my already deployed contract on the blockchain

Please be elaborate on the answer with some code as I am very new to solidity.

```
//deployed contract
struct User {
    address wallet_address;  
    string userId;
    string first_name;
    string last_name;
}

mapping(address => User) users; 
mapping(string => address) walletAccount;
mapping(address => uint) public balanceOf;

User public newUser;
uint public length;
address public owner;

constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

event userCreated (
    address wallet_address,
    string  userId,
    string first_name,
    string last_name
);

function createNewUser(address userAcc, string memory _id, string memory firstName, string memory lastName) public {
    User storage user = users[userAcc];
    users[userAcc] = User(userAcc,_id,firstName,lastName);
}

function getUser(address _userAddress, string memory _lastName) public view returns (address, string memory, string memory, string memory) {
    User memory user = users[_userAddress];
    return (users[_userAddress].wallet_address, users[_userAddress].userId, users[_userAddress].first_name, users[_userAddress].last_name);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean by using `getUser()` function?!

Comment: Yes by using getUser() or by some how fetching the data from the deployed contract

Comment: @georgesingh you want to know how to interact it with javascript?

Comment: no i want to know how to interact with a different smart contract solidity but I am open to know with javascript as well.

Comment: You must have each users `address` and `lastName` to access contracts data. Otherwise you can't.

Comment: Ok so technically I can't make anything like an array in my new smart contract to fetch the data from the deployed contract and without passing the address and lastName parameters I can't get the data from my deployed contract . Ok so could you please help me with the code how to get the user details from the deployed contract with passing address and lastName as I am very new to solidity. Thanks